# Map of strings and generic functions in Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a map that will map strings to functions. Not all functions have the same signature. For example, I'd like to have something like this:

```
rf := map[string]func(...interface{}) error{
    "FirstName":        validateExistence(a.FirstName, "FirstName is required."),
    "Postcode":         validateMatchPattern(a.Postcode, `^\d{5}$`, "Could not match pattern for postcode."),
    "Address":          validateLength(a.Address, 0, 35, "Address must have up to 35 chars."),
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
cannot use validateExistence("FirstName is required.") (type func(string) error) as type func(...interface {}) error in map value
```

If I change the map declaration to `map[string]func(f string, m string) error` the error for the `FirstName` is solved, but I get other errors for the other two functions:

```
cannot use validateMatchPattern(a.Postcode, "^\\d{5}$", "Could not match pattern for postcode.") (type error) as type func(string) error in map value
cannot use validateLength(a.Address, 0, 35, "Address must have up to 35 chars.") (type error) as type func(string) error in map value
```

I understand the issue is in the map declaration, in the `func(...interface{})` to be more precise. This part must have the same signatures as the function I'm using as key.

So, my question is: is there any other way to declare the map that can hold functions with different signatures?

Comment: You’re not putting functions /object/ in your map, you put whatever the functions returns. Or I’m missing something?

Comment: both validateMatchPattern and validateLength are returning error value

Comment: How might you call one of these functions?

Comment: @mgagnon The functions return another funtions, which then will be called when needed.

Comment: A map is almost certainly the wrong tool here. Note that every static map (i.e. there are no inserts or deletes at runtime) can also be expressed with a switch/case statement, which is more flexible in terms of types.

Comment: @DavidMaze The functions are returning another function. The idea is iterate on the map and call the functions when needed, create an array of errors and then return it.

Comment: @Peter Can be. The idea about using map is to create a correlation between the required fields and the function that will validate them. This will be done for each country, so that's why I thought about having a simple map[string]function would be easier to implement the validations for each country.

Comment: What's the signature of your `validateFoo` functions? I assume those are high-order functions and their signatures are something like `validateExistence(field string, message string) func (string) error`?

Answer (score 1):

If I was designing this, I'd break this problem down like so:

1. I want a map of validators, each of which takes a string and returns a human-readable error.
2. I want to be able to pair a simple validator that returns a yes-or-no answer with an error message.
3. I need a set of simple validators.

Note that in all of these cases you need functions that return functions.  The length validator, for example, can be:

```
func validateLength(min, max int) func(string) bool {
        return func(s string) bool {
                return len(s) >= min && len(s) <= max
        }
}
```

Then you can wrap this in a function that produces the error

```
func makeValidator(f func(string) bool, msg string) func(string) error {
        return func(s string) error {
                if !f(s) {
                        return errors.New(msg)
                }
                return nil
        }
}
```

Now you have a couple of layers that build the functions that go into the map, so you can create

```
rt := map[string]func(string) error {
        "Address": makeValidator(
                validateLength(0, 35),
                "Address must have up to 35 chars."
        )
}
```

This doesn't pair it with the specific field (and indeed the suggestion from comments to just write this in code is probably a good one) but if you needed this to really be generic you could use [reflection](https://godoc.org/reflect) to look at the contents of a structure.